# Save memory while looping through big list

Tags: python-3.x, out-of-memory

I'm trying to loop through x! permutations and I'm running out of memory after 10! permutations

Here's the code please help me clear the memory out

```
def test_your_might(NUMBER_OF_MARBLES, marbles):
    angle = 360 / NUMBER_OF_MARBLES
    angles = [angle * n for n in range(1, NUMBER_OF_MARBLES + 1)]

    Fx = []
    Fy = []

    for n in range(0, NUMBER_OF_MARBLES):
        angle = radians(angles[n])
        Fx.append(cos(angle) * marbles[n])
        Fy.append(sin(angle) * marbles[n])

    return sqrt(pow(sum(Fx), 2) + pow(sum(Fy), 2))


def brute_force_solution(NUMBER_OF_MARBLES):
    possibilities = permutations((_ for _ in range(1, NUMBER_OF_MARBLES + 1)))
    best_solution = None

    for possibility in possibilities:
        solution = test_your_might(NUMBER_OF_MARBLES, possibility)

        if best_solution is None or solution < best_solution[1]:
            best_solution = (str(possibility), solution)
    return best_solution
```

The aim of the game is to balance marbles on a circular board. Each marble weighs n units. marble 1 weighs 1, 2 weighs 2, etc.

I don't think that the problem is coming from my method test_your_might, but if you find a way to make it faster that'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are running out of memory.  10 marbles works on my machine; above that, the number of permutations may just take too long unless there is memory leakage, which you could look at with with the Module gc.

You can improve the function test_your_might by using a a Johnson-Trotter permutation generator algorithm (available in Python), which cycles through permutations by interchanging only 2 entries at a time, thereby reducing your loop through all marbles to processing just 2 entries.

Comment: Do you have any examples for Johnson-Trotter permutations? I looked online but didn't find anything

Comment: http://argskwargs.io/blog/python/johnson-trotter-algorithm/  is where I found the one I used.  It is not as fast as permutations from itertools, but would reduce the order n calculation.  It would be better to have a version from C, which I assume is the case for permutations; certainly there is one in C that could be connected.  Just going from 10 to 11 increases the time by a factor of 11, so there should be a better way to get close, perhaps by moving around a high-scoring permutation by singl pair exchanges around the high scorer, moving slowly up the ladder.

Comment: Also called a gray code.  A python search finds several entries